# Does FluentNH's PersistenceSpecification allow XML mappings to be tested?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, integration-testing

Is it possible to use Fluent NHibernate's PersistenceSpecification to test NHibernate mappings done via XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PersistenceSpecification](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Persistence_specification_testing)  takes session as its only parameter, so I do not see reason why not.

Comment: Be aware though that you might run into problems if you try to test your collection mappings if access strategy is through private field rather then property.